# Resource Dictionary Not Found When App is Published

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, resourcedictionary

I have written a WPF/C# application that I am trying to publish. The application currently uses two resource dictionaries to switch between themes. Here is the App.xaml file, which specifies two resource dictionaries:

```
<Application x:Class="TopDeck.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         xmlns:visualizationToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         xmlns:chartingprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#d0157820" x:Key="muddyBrush"/>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="MenuFont">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="DarkTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="LightTheme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>


</Application>
```

I have two files, DarkTheme.xaml and LightTheme.xaml, which are resource dictionaries. I have not included them because I do not think that their content is relevant here.

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs, I have a method for switching between two themes. This method works when I run my code within Visual Studio 2013:

```
private void ChangeTheme(int themeChoice)
{
    ResourceDictionary dict;
    var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
    path = path.Replace("bin\\Debug", "");
    path = path.Replace("bin\\Release", "");

    if (themeChoice == 0)
    {
        dict = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "LightTheme.xaml"), FileMode.Open));
            theme = "LightTheme.xaml";
    }
    else
    {
        dict = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "DarkTheme.xaml"), FileMode.Open));
        theme = "DarkTheme.xaml";
    }

    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);

}
```

The problem is that when I publish this application and I try to run it, I get this error message:

```
{"Could not find file 'C:\\Users\\Emerald\\AppData\\Local\\Apps\\2.0\\JTHXX0YW.KTK\\1MZ2M8ZP.TV0\\topd..tion_1428230028859fe5_0001.0000_ec5ac614e9be24b1\\DarkTheme.xaml'.":"C:\\Users\\Emerald\\AppData\\Local\\Apps\\2.0\\JTHXX0YW.KTK\\1MZ2M8ZP.TV0\\topd..tion_1428230028859fe5_0001.0000_ec5ac614e9be24b1\\DarkTheme.xaml"}
```

Does anyone know what I can do to maintain resource dictionary switching in my application, but avoid this error? Is there a way to specify that I would like DarkTheme.xaml and LightTheme.xaml to exist in the published application? If not, is there a way to reference these resource dictionaries without explicitly loading the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess by publish you mean publish via ClickOnce. So to include your DarkTheme.xaml and LightTheme.xaml go to their properties and set build action to "Content".Then you can check (at project properties > Publish > Application Files that they are included indeed). But, consider also the following way to achieve your goal:

```
var themeDict = new ResourceDictionary();
var uriPath = string.Format("/{0};component/DarkTheme.xaml", 
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name);
var uri = new Uri(uriPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
themeDict.Source = uri;        
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(themeDict);
```

What you do here is construct url to your (already existing) DarkTheme.xaml file, and then telling ResourceDictionary that url. With this, you don't need to change build action to Content, nor do you need to deploy anything.

Comment: Thanks! I used your code and it worked. For other people visiting this page, I was publishing using ClickOnce.